# Set disabled input background color after autofill

Tags: css

I'm creating a form where once it has been submitted, I want to remove the background colour of the input.

If I use Google Autofill on an input, the background color and color attributes are ignored.

In dev tools it's showing that my styles SHOULD be visible, but they're not.

```
input:disabled, textarea:disabled, .disabled {
  background: #060301;
  color: #f0eef3;
}

/* Annoyingly we have to override Chrome styles */
input:-webkit-autofill:disabled, 
textarea:-webkit-autofill:disabled,
input:-internal-autofill-selected {
  background: #060301!important;
  color: #f0eef3!important;
}
```

It works fine unless autofill was used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can re-set the value of the input field right before disabling it. That will reset Chrome's autofill status.

```js
inputField.value = inputField.value
inputField.disabled = true
```

The only way to achieve the desired effect - at least visually - with only CSS is to colorize the background using a large inset box shadow rather than setting the background color. The latter is locked by the user agent stylesheet.

Answer (score -1):

Set a background color for all disabled input elements of `type="text":` You can add the `disabled` attribute in html and add background.

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp)

```css
input[type=text]:enabled {
  background: #ffff00;
}

input[type=text]:disabled {
  background: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  First name: <input type="text" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" value="Mouse"><br>
  Country: <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="Disneyland">
</form>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix the issue. I'm starting to think this is a Chrome styling defect.

I'm not having an issue with setting the background, it's only when the input has been filled in using Google Chrome's "Autofill" feature - after which the background cannot be set, it seems.